# What word means to work yourself into redundancy?

Tags: single-word-requests

I heard a word recently and totally forgot it. It means to work towards rendering yourself unnecessary. Something tells me it starts with an A.

Please help,...my brain is going crazy :-)

Comment: [Obsolescence?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsolescence)

Comment: As [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automation), *The biggest benefit of **automation** is that it saves labor*. I always used to "automate" as much as possible of my daily workload. But being self-employed, I never made myself redundant - I just found more other stuff to do.

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like automation? To automate your job.

Automate: to displace or make obsolete by automation. (Meaning 3, dictionary.com)